# Good site for nutritional info

Tags: nutrient-composition

I cook my breakfast from several raw ingredients (about 12) and was trying to come up with caloric and nutritional content for the same, for few ingredients I could get details on Wikipedia, a bit of google brings few other sites, though I am wondering is there a comprehensive listing of most known edible items, what is the best site for that?

Comment: Do the sites that typically come up on Google for queries of the form "(food) nutrition" (e.g. nutritiondata.self.com) not satisfy your needs?

Comment: To me, this looks like a poll. Close votes anyone, or do you people think it can be answered objectively?

Comment: @Jefromi no sites like nutritiondata.self.com doesn't have information for many ingredients

Comment: @rumtscho It can be answered objectively by providing a site which gives comprehensive listing of ingredients (is such site exists)

Comment: @AnuragUniyal what do you call "comprehensive"? I doubt that it is possible to make a site which includes everything which has ever been eaten, it will always only have a list of common ingredients - but what is common varies across the world. And how about other quality criteria beside completeness? On a side note, which ingredients did you miss on nutrition data? AFAIK, they include the complete USDA database on food (they are practically a frontend for it).

Comment: @rumtscho that why I think this question is important, there are so many sites which provide such data, some have very few ingredients, some are front end to USDA, so for a newbie I think this question with answer will help what sites to visit first

Comment: @AnuragUniyal it will only help if there is one site which is clearly better than all others. The more likely thing to happen is that everybody will post their favorite site as an answer - this is a classic example of a non constructive question.

Comment: OK, there are three flags as "not constructive" already, and I don't see anybody coming up with a single definitive answer. So I am closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for it for day and I think best database available is @ http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/list, though search is not as good, I couldn't find some items which I could find after downloading their database.

It also has a [downloadable database](http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=8964) available

Plus have a [desktop app](http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=5720)

Answer (score 0):

you might want to give the recipe analyzer over at calorie counter a try.

http://caloriecount.about.com/cc/account/flog_add.php?tab=new_recipe

Input ingredients and quantities and it will calculate nutritional info. It is a bit rough around the edges and you will probably have to tweak it, but it's a start. :)